# How does "list[x]" get only a single number from "list"?

Tags: python, list

```
list=(1,2,3,4)
for x in range(len(list)):
    print(list[x])
```

```
1
2
3
4
```

but `print(list)` repeats the whole list 4 times, i.e.

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
```

How does the `x` in the `print(list[x])` cause only single numbers to come out? Like how could you put what the `[x]` is doing in English?

Comment: One thing: never define a variable with the name `list`. It is a keyword in `python`. Also, lists are usually defined using the square brackets >>> `lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Please take look at this article to get started [The basics of Indexing](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-basics-of-indexing-and-slicing-python-lists-2d12c90a94cf) and [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Comment: @tanmay_garg You're right, though `list` is a builtin, not a keyword (otherwise you wouldn't be able to assign to it), and the parentheses create a tuple, not a list.

Comment: @tanmay_garg It is a function, not a keyword.

Comment: This is not a comprehension, so I've rewritten the title accordingly. Also make sure to use descriptive titles in the future, e.g. "How do I do x?" instead of "Question about x". BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: @TheMaker It's also not a function, but a callable type, though that doesn't really matter for a newbie.

Answer (score 2):

The 'x' represents a number, which changes with each iteration of the for loop. When you do list[x], you are getting the xth number in list, starting at 0.

Comment: Can x become a value depending on how you put it in the for loop ie                        
 "for x in range(list)", is x now a value but in "for x in range(len(list))" x is the index?

Comment: And it's the len function that is making x an index?

Answer (score 1):

`x` represents the index within the `list`. Using `list[x]` is actually picking the element in the `x` position from the `list`.

Answer (score 1):

For each time through the loop `x` takes on values 0, 1, 2, etc. `list[x]` is then `list[0]`, `list[1]`, where the square brackets extract a single list element.

Note: for good python form consider using a different variable name (such as `lst`) to avoid confusion with builtin python names.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the program that in range of list's length (4), run the following command:

```
print(list)
```

So it will print all the list items 4 times.

> "Like how could you put what the [x] is doing in English?"

```
for item in list:
    print(item)
```

And as other friends said, don't use "list" for variable name.